# Code Signing not showing Provisioning Profile - Xcode 5.1.

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, provisioning-profile

Hi, I recently upgraded to **Xcode 5.1** now I can not find Provisioning Profile in `Projects->Target->Code Signing` section of settings. Before **Xcode 5.1**, I used to change Provisioning Profile to desired profile from **Provisioning Profile** option then it starts to appear in code signing identity debug or release section as shown in image below.

[image]

But now I am not given this options in **Code Signing** so I can't change the debug or release profile it only show automatic or identities in keychain.

How an I change to the desired provisioning profile?

**Update:**

I tried using the 000000B-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 UUID code at User Defined Provisioning Profile and it accepts and build and displays Provisioning profile at Code Signing. But it is not resolving Provisioning profile name at User Defined Profiles.

Comment: Did you try re-installing certificates, without double clicking on the certificate, try to import to keychain by file->import items. Then quit Xcode and reopen.

Comment: Check the Bundle Identifier you used in your `iOS App` and in your `provisioning profile`. Add Same then `Clean` you project and try ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I filed a bug on this. You can manually do it but a pain in the rear. This to me is a huge bug. I hope they fix it soon.

Answer (score 9):

I was stuck with same issue and finally got it done here u can look for the following screen shots..

go to **Code signing** in the build setting and change the **Provisional Profile** **NONE** to the provisional profile you like to test

[image]

then change the Code **signing identity** to test your Application on device with the suitable bundle identifier look for the following screen shot

[image]

If you find this Answer is correct then Vote up lets other also can solve their problem.
Thanks

Comment: Changing this Code Signing setting triggered XCode to realize it needed to refresh my provisioning profiles... it ended up returning this setting back to what it had originally when I clicked "Fix" in the error popup, but then my app ran, so something was automatically corrected behind the scenes!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have 'all' and not 'basic' display mode selected.

Answer (score 1):

Login in [Apple Dev](https://developer.apple.com/) website and go to  the [profile list view](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action), then download the profile and double click to install, then you can see it in **Code Signing** list.

Comment: Do you set Bundle identifier in plist file same with app id in the profile.

Answer (score 0):

Check your bundle Id and make sure that you have installed your required profile.

Then Click on Provisioning profile option and select a profile(see the option below code signing identity).

Now you need to select certificate under code signing identity.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure:

Our team encountered an afternoon of frustration trying to open an app or update an app compiled with **Xcode 5.1** on **iOS 7.1** device with a tardy profile. Download and install a new profile (as necessary) then:

Make sure the `BUNDLE IDENTIFIER in Xcodeʻs GENERAL` view for your project matches what the profile reads on your Dev web portal, and then THAT profile is installed in Xcode verbatim. Select that profile in your BUILD setting, and you could be solved by now (the App installed on devices without issue), but we also noticed we could to go back to GENERAL view and the FIX button actually worked: it fixed the "not found" profile

Answer (score 0):

Try by creating an archive. I attached an iphone and tried to create an archive which result in no provisioning profile error. But now the option in the target to select a provisioning profile was there from which I was able to choose the provisioning profile

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem, just had to open Preferences and refreshed the screen under Accounts - View Details.

Answer (score 0):

The provisioning profile had no options for me. I had registered for the Apple Developers program recently. I followed these steps and then clean and build. It worked.

[Import User to XCODE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/import_signing_assets.html)